# Retrieve the 13-digit authentication code via the API

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the REST API v2.
When creating an envelope we set the signer.requireIDLookup = true so that Docusign launches the list of questions to authenticate the recipient.

After the signature is completed, is there a way to retrieve the 13-digit transaction number that gets generated? I can see it in the certificate pdf, but I haven't found a way to retrieve it via the API.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by transaction number, do you mean the envelopeID?

Comment: What is it called when you see it in the certificate PDF?

Comment: In the certificate it's a thirteen digit code called Transaction: ![Certificate Transaction](http://i42.tinypic.com/a4oscn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is the Get Envelope Recipient Status call.  Look at this page from the REST API guide which describes it in more detail:

[Get Envelope Recipient Status](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Recipient%20Status.htm)

Looking at the sample response on that page, you'll see that it shows the boolean for requireIdLookup and also there's a recipientAuthenticationStatus section.

```
{
  "agents":[]
  "carbonCopies":[],
  "certifiedDeliveries":[],
  "currentRoutingOrder":"String content",
  "editors":[],
  "inPersonSigners":[],
  "intermediaries":[],
  "recipientCount":"String content",
  "signers":[{
    "deliveredDateTime": "String content",
    "recipientAuthenticationStatus":{
      "(authentication status result)":
        "eventTimestamp":"String content"
        "status":"String content"
      }
    },
    "recipientId": "String content",
    "requireIdLookup": "String content",
    "roleName":"String content",
    "routingOrder": "String content",
    "signedDateTime": "String content",
    "status": "String content",
    "email": "String content",
    "name": "String content"  }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ergin, I looked at that object in the status update coming from Docusign Connet and it only says "status":"pass". It doesn't provide the actual code.

Comment: I'm guessing the API doesn't support this feature. Do you have a way to provide user input for the next release?